# Replacement for flash bulb

Tags: flash, vintage, zeiss

I have this cool dish shaped flash thingy. It's from before the dinosaurs so it takes flash bulbs that burn up in one go. I'm hoping I could modify it to a pure electric flash.

I though some replacement bulb must exist but I had no luck finding them.

[image]

Comment: For modern versions of the 'real thing', have a look at movie props suppliers. I don't know that particular bulb type but I worked on several series of The Crown where they were going through bayonet-style flash bulbs by the pallette-load. The flash units had all been modified to take 4 modern D-cells.

Comment: I'm no photography expert but I'm certain it can be modified. Whether *you* can do it *without accidentally destroying anything* is another question.

Comment: One reason why those aren't popular any more: When the flash "burns" (yes, it's  rather slow process) the glass of the bulb literally melts, and as glass isn't actually glowing when hot, you can severely burn your fingers or anything else when you "eject" the used bulb.

Answer (score 2):

The flash is a german make produced by Zeiss. Replacement bulbs are called RF1B Blitzlampen (translates to flash bulbs). You may have luck with that as a search string. Form time to time, the tend to show up on ebay, or a photo store sells them as vintage stuff for around 15 Euro/Dollars a pack.

There is also the german manual page here: https://www.kameramuseum.de/blitz/zeiss-ikon/ikoblitz-6/ikoblitz-6-anleit.html which states, that you can also use bulbs of the type AG1, but should then use the clear part of the cover of the flash over the bulb to protect from potential burst of the bulb.

Also, the B at the end of some bulbs seems to stand for blue hue of the light.

[image: AG1 Flash Bulb]

[image: RF1B Flash Bulbs]

Answer (score 2):

Original flash bulbs aren't all that rare -- last time I looked, they were pretty easy to find on eBay (maybe Etsy too, these days).  There are several kinds, however; the bayonet style (base like an old style incandescent tail light bulb), the push-in "M" style, and the "AG" ("all glass") type with no applied metal base.  I can't tell for certain from the photo which kind your Ikoblitz unit takes.

I'm not aware of any electronic flash units that plug into a flash bulb socket like the one in that reflector, however -- the first of those that I recall were for FlipFlash or Flashbar (late Kodak Pocket Instamatic and Polaroid SX-70 family, respectively); instead, there were and are many different electronic flashes that would mount in the same "hot shoe" that Ikoblitz does -- an accessory shoe on the camera with contacts wired to the sync system in the camera shutter.  Even current manufacture add-on flashes made for DSLRs should work with a hot shoe on (as an extreme example) late 1940s vintage leaf shutters with PC sync socket (though you'd need a shoe adapter that connects to that socket in that case).

The reason electronic flash won't work with bulb sockets is voltage -- electronic flash uses between 300 and 450 volts, while bulbs need between 1.5 and about 21 volts.  There isn't enough power in a bulb flash to fire a xenon flash tube, but most electronic flashes use a simple external contact switch to fire (some with protection against high voltage on the contacts, older ones often without).

Comment: Just to expand a little bit. The electronic flash is a xenon gas filled tube that is fired by ionizing the gas with a high voltage kicker allowing it to conduct the main power from a high density capacitor which supplies the energy to make the light. Flash Bulbs consist of a nothing more than very fine **Aluminum Wires** . A simple battery heats a piece of the wire up enough to burn, setting the rest of the aluminum burning.

Comment: @user10216038 Some are magnesium instead of aluminum.

Comment: @Michael C - Magnesium has a lower exothermic reaction *(Heat & Light)* and costs much more than Aluminum. Why would anyone manufacture an inferior product that costs much more intentionally?

Comment: @Michael C - https://camerapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Flashbulbs . *The first actual flashbulb was the Vacu-Blitz, made in 1929 by the German company Hauff-Leonar AG on basis of a patent from Johannes Ostermeier. This patent describes the application of ultra-thin alumnium foil (0,5µ) in a glass bulb with a low pressure oxygen atmosphere. It was the first flash bulb design, which could be reproduced on a larger industrial scale.*

Comment: @user10216038 Magnesium was used in most early flashbulbs for whatever reason(s).  As to why they used magnesium, perhaps it was because the makers of magnesium flash powder, which preceded self-contained flash bulbs, realized their flash powder business was about to take a nose dive and they started making bulbs too. In addition to magnesium, the bulbs were filled with oxygen rather than natural air.

Comment: Just because magnesium is currently more expensive than aluminum does not necessarily mean this has always been the case. I don't know what the comparative costs were in the 1930s and 1940s, but prices of commodities can fluctuate wildly depending on what products need/use them and how demand for those products goes up/down. The price of beaver pelts, for instance, skyrocketed when European royals decided hats made from them were fashionable. The price fell to almost nothing when beaver skin hats fell out of fashion a few years later.

Comment: Kodak's "Magicubes" required no external electrical current at all. Instead, a plastic mechanical striker in the camera struck a wire on the bottom of the flashcube. The force of the wire's movement against a small pyrotechnic (much like a percussion cap used in early revolvers, only much smaller) inside the flash cube provided a spark that fired the flash.

Comment: General Electric made magnesium-based flash bulbs in 1927, two years before Vacublitz introduced their aluminum based bulbs in 1929. There's been a long-running argument by some Europeans that Vacublitz was the first. They later switched over to a magnesium-aluminum based alloy called *hydronalium* which is prominently mentioned in the same camerapedia article you cited above. Perhaps the combination of aluminum and magnesium combined provided a fuller spectrum than either metal alone. The introduction of hydronalium was at about the same time that color emulsions started to become viable.

Answer (score 1):

The basic reason you haven't found simple "plug and play" electronic bulbs that would work in a non-modified flash made for single use bulbs is that it's not really feasible.

The energy for single use flash bulbs is contained in the chemicals inside the bulb, not in the small amount of current applied to them to initiate a chemical reaction that releases the energy stored in the chemicals.

For an electronic flash tube, much more voltage is required than what is provided to chemical flash bulbs. In order to use a reusable gas filled tube with vintage pieces designed to be used with disposable flash bulbs would require essentially building a modern flash's electronics inside the vintage housing.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the guide number diagram, you get a guide number of 20m at 25ASA which corresponds to a guide number of 40m at about ISO100, at very wide angle illumination.  The reflector cannot really hold a candle to a more modern flash tube reflector.  An equivalent electronic flash would have significant energy to dispose of: the Metz hammerhead flashes are specified as having 45m guide number at ISO100 for 35mm illumination angle (narrower than what you appear to have there).  They store about 70J of energy if I remember correctly.  A typical strong cattle fence has about 3J of energy and comparable voltage.  There has been some stupid trend in Japan of children shocking others with parts from old flashes, actually causing some fatalities.

The combination of the metal reflector and the contacts in the sockets is not at all proof against touch.  In a hammerhead flash, a significant part of the handle is filled with the flash capacitor.  In a cobrahead flash, the tilt joint is typically filled with capacitor.

Getting a complete electronic flash with capacitor and charging circuitry in the place of the bulb while retaining a comparable power to the chemical flash bulbs would be infeasible.  Putting the charging circuitry elsewhere and only placing the flash tube there would mean that lethal voltage would be running around open metal parts.

In short, bad idea.  If you want a show prop, invest in the original bulbs.  They are set off using voltage that is not dangerous to humans.

Comment: It's not voltage that is dangerous to humans, it is total current (amperage). In high school physics class we had a Van de Graaff generator that put out several hundreds of KVolts! It was safe to touch as long as you didn't mind your hair standing on end. But the total current is very low as the resistance was practically zero.

Comment: Opps! I just killed someone (theoretically). The reason Van de Graaff generators are harmless when used properly to make one's hair stand on end is because the resistance is almost infinite, not near zero.

Comment: @MichaelC You did read the part about 70J of energy being stored in the flash capacitor?  Currents of heart-stopping strengths are sustained long enough to actually do this, and the voltage is sufficient to drive them through a human body at that strength.  There is actually enough current available to leave a serious pock in a screwdriver you use for discharging the capacitor.  This isn't low-energy static electricity that gives you a bristle and maybe a jolt and haha.  Repairing electronic flashes is not a joke and the capacitors can sustain voltage a long time after switch-off.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of *current* inside an electronic flash. It is the amount of *current*, not the *voltage*, that makes it harmful to humans.

Comment: Without voltage driving the current through the high resistance of human skin, there is no dangerous current.  A spanner falling on the contacts of a truck battery will melt because of the high current the battery is able to deliver, yet a human is not in any danger from touching the electrodes (at least when not doing it concurrently with a melting spanner).

Comment: That depends on how wet the human is, what kind of materials their shoes are made of, where they're standing and whether the truck is grounded (many bulk tankers are required to have grounding straps that contact the road, even when in transit).

Comment: @MichaelC Frankly, that's just bad equivocation.  For car batteries, the largest danger is in closing the circuit bypassing the human, for flash capacitors, the largest danger is in closing the circuit across the human.  Being unable to distinguish the respective risks does not really make for a useful contribution to the discussion.

Comment: You said truck battery, not car. Trucks tend to have four 12V batteries in a parallel configuration. That's about 2,000 CCA @ 12V.

Comment: But be that as it may, It doesn't take much voltage to kill a human. It's the current that does the job. As little as 100 to 200 milliamperes for 1-2 seconds can be lethal if it passes through the human's ventricular nerves. In fact, [lower voltage can be more damaging than higher voltage](https://academic.oup.com/ptj/article-abstract/46/9/968/4637975) due to human physiological reactions.

Comment: @MichaelC You apparently don't understand that 12V is harmless to the touch given the resistance of the human body, whether supplied by four 12V batteries in a parallel configuration or by 8 AAA batteries in a row.  In either situation the resistance of the human body will limit the current to the same value.  When handling battery connectors, there is no problem touching the chassis with one hand while touching a 12V cable to the starter motor.  For touching the cable to the chassis directly without intervening human however, truck battery or AAA stack make a murderous difference.